# who and w report my user ten times..but I have only four pts open

Tags: who, w, pts

The command `w` said

```
 02:50:35 up 20:54, 10 users,  load average: 1,07, 1,29, 1,41
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
myuser :0       -                lun05   ?xdm?   1:38m  0.11s /bin/sh /etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc
myuser pts/0    -                02:06   31:29   2:45   7:35  /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal
myuser pts/1    -                02:48    1:35   0.16s  0.16s bash
myuser pts/2    -                02:48    3.00s  0.05s  0.00s w
myuser pts/3    -                02:49    0.00s  0.00s  7:35  /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal
myuser pts/5    -                02:24    0.00s  0.00s  7:35  /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal
myuser pts/7    -                01:13    0.00s  0.00s  7:35  /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal
myuser pts/8    -                01:33    0.00s  0.00s  7:35  /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal
myuser pts/9    -                01:31    0.00s  0.00s  7:35  /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal
myuser pts/10   -                18:20    0.00s  0.00s  7:35  /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal
```

The command who output is identical

But the pts oper are only 4

```
find /dev/pts/
/dev/pts/
/dev/pts/3
/dev/pts/2
/dev/pts/1
/dev/pts/0
/dev/pts/ptmx
```

Why w and who report 10 users and 10 pts opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat difficult to explain but `/dev/pts/n` are just virtual devices which only serve to move data form the keyboard to the program to standard output and aren't actual files. There will be a new `pts` spawned for every application you run which is why they sometimes won't match up.